# Is it possible to make acids and bases in amphiprotic solvents other than water

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solutions, ph

In such solvents, could there be chemicals which could donate/accept protons, and if so could their solutions display acidic/basic properties?

Comment: Organic chemistry is filled with examples of chemicals that accept or donate protons in solvents other than water

Comment: You may find useful reviewing of search results for 
[site:libretexts.org OR site:stackexchange.com OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu acids bases amphiprotic solvents](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alibretexts.org+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Awikipedia.org+OR+site%3Ahyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu+acids+bases+amphiprotic+solvents)

Answer (score 3):

Certainly! There are various definitions for acid and base, such as [Brønsted–Lowry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory), that describe acid/base reactions as the transfer of protons ($\ce{H+}$), without requiring hydroxyl ions ($\ce{OH-}$), and [Lewis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases), which goes beyond $\ce{H+}$ and deals with *electron exchange*.

An example of a Brønsted–Lowry acid/base system is ammonia as the solvent. The ammonium ion ($\ce{NH4+}$) corresponds to the hydronium ion, and the amide ion ($\ce{NH2-}$) to the hydroxide ion.

An example of a Lewis acid is $\ce{BF3}$, an [electron acceptor](https://xaktly.com/LewisAcidBase.html) rather than a proton donor.